# getline and cin used one after another skips next inputs

Tags: c++, inheritance, aggregation, cin, getline

I am writing a C++ program to demonstrate the Aggregation concept,given as an example in a book. The code comprises of 4 classes(in a file) and a main function(in another file).
The classes are as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
/*#define  SYNC_CLEAR {\
                    cin.clear();\
                    cin.sync();\
                }
*/
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

class Student
{
private:
    string school;
    string degree;
public:
    void input_data()
    {
        cout<<"Enter School name and degree name \n";
        getline(cin,school);
        getline(cin,degree);
    }
    void show_data() const
    {
        cout<<"School :"<<school<<",Degree: "<<degree<<"\n";
    }

};

class Employee
{
private:
    string name;
    unsigned int number;
public:
    void input_data()
    {
        string str;
        cout<<"Enter Name and number \n";
        getline(cin,name);
        cin>>number;
    }
    void show_data() const
    {
        cout<<"Name :"<<name<<",number: "<<number<<"\n";
    }
};


/************************Aggregation starts from here**********************************/
class Manager
{
private:
    string title;
    double dues;
    Employee emp;   // object of one class as an attribute to other class
    Student stu;    // object of one class as an attribute to other class
public:
    **void input_data()
    {
        emp.input_data();   // call by object of Employee class
        cout<<"Enter Title and Dues \n";
        /*********Problem comes here*****************/
        getline(cin,title);
        cin>>dues;
        /**************************/
        stu.input_data();   // call by object of Student class
    }**
    void show_data() const
    {
        emp.show_data();
        cout<<"Title :"<<title<<",Dues: "<<dues<<"\n";
        stu.show_data();
    }   
};

class Scientist
{
private:
    int pubs;
    Employee emp;   // object of one class as an attribute to other class
    Student stu;    // object of one class as an attribute to other class
public:
    void input_data()
    {
        emp.input_data();   // call by object of Employee class
        cout<<"Enter no of pubs \n";
        cin>>pubs;
        stu.input_data();   // call by object of Student class
    }
    void show_data() const
    {
        emp.show_data();
        cout<<" pubs :"<<pubs<<"\n";
        stu.show_data();
    }   
};
```

main function follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "aggregation.h"

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Manager m1;
    Scientist s1,s2;
    cout<<"Data for Manager\n";
    m1.input_data();

    cout<<"Data for Sci 1\n";
    s1.input_data();

    cout<<"Data for Sci 2\n";
    s2.input_data();

    cout<<"Data for Manager\n";
    m1.show_data();

    cout<<"Data for Sci 1\n";
    s1.show_data();

    cout<<"Data for Sci 2\n";
    s2.show_data();

    return 0;
}
```

The problem comes in Class Manager in input_data() function (highlighted in bold) . I am attaching output at console

```
hduser@M-1939:~/Dropbox/c++/lafore/inhertiance$ g++ -g aggregation.cpp -o aggregation
hduser@M-1939:~/Dropbox/c++/lafore/inhertiance$ ./aggregation 
Data for Manager
Enter Name and number 
vivek 
100
***Enter Title and Dues 
sr manager***
Enter School name and degree name 
Data for Sci 1
Enter Name and number 
Enter no of pubs 
Enter School name and degree name 
Data for Sci 2
Enter Name and number 
Enter no of pubs 
Enter School name and degree name 
Data for Manager
Name :vivek,number: 100
Title :,Dues: 0
School :,Degree: 
Data for Sci 1
Name :,number: 6299824
 pubs :6299824
School :,Degree: 
Data for Sci 2
Name :,number: 2092888488
 pubs :6299112
School :,Degree:
```

I looked at some links telling using cin.clear() and cin.sync(), but it did not work as well. Got problem,not like this,different but still a similar problem .
Any lead?

EDIT 1 : **I used changed the sequence of input from 1 : getline 2: cin to 1:cin 2: cin.ignore() 3: getline and it is working. But can anyone tell me how? Why it did not work the previous way.**

EDIT 2 : I forgot to put cin.ignore() after cin>>number in input_data() of Employee class. Did it got it working. Although a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is `cin.ignore()` after a `cin`.
This is what happens:
When you use `std::getline`, it will get whatever is on that line, up until a newline character, but `cin` doesn't actually remove the newline character after performing a read, so your `std::getline` only gets an empty string.

Comment: it still doesn't work. By the way, problem starts just after I enter "title" ,in given question, "sr manager"

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
cin.ignore(256,'\n');
```

After every cin call to clean the buffer.

256 is the number of characters to ignore, '\n' is the delimiting character.

For safety purposes, maybe use

```
std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()
```

as the limiting amount of characters; I simply like 256.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/